# Query max 4 posts from each category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I was created a `custom post type` `dishmenu`. There are **4** categories in my `dishmenu` like *`Special,Breakfast,Lunch,Dinner`*. Now I want to get the maximum 4 records from each category if available.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php
$menucat = get_terms('menu_category');
foreach($menucat as $category){
    $menuQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'dishmenu','posts_per_page'=>4,'category_name'=>$category->slug));
    if($menuQuery->have_posts()):
        while($menuQuery->have_posts()): $menuQuery->the_post();
            $price = json_decode(json_encode(get_post_meta($menuQuery->post->ID)),false);
            echo '<div class="element-item '.$category->slug.' col-sm-6" data-category="'.$category->slug.'" >
                    <div class="dish-menu-item">
                        <div class="dish-border-circle">
                            <div class="dish-menu-left"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dish-menu-body">
                            <h4>'.get_the_title().'<span class="pull-right"><span class="error-text">'.$price->Price[0].'</span><sub>$</sub></span></h4>
                            <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dish-menu-right text-center">
                            <p style="padding:2px; display:inline-block;"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
        echo '<div class="element-item '.$category->slug.' col-sm-6" data-category="'.$category->slug.'" >
                No posts found in '.$category->slug.'
            </div>';
    endif;
}
?>
```

Now the problem is that everytime else block has been executed.

Comment: Are you used custom taxonomy  for categories ?

Comment: yeah. `menu_category` is the taxonomy.

Comment: You need to used tax_query Query in WP_Query. please check below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to used `tax_query` Query in [`WP_Query`](https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/)

Please check below query

```
$arg=array(
    'post_type'=>'dishmenu',
    'posts_per_page'=>4,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array('taxonomy' => 'menu_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' =>  $category->slug,
        'include_children' => true)
        )
    );
$menuQuery = new WP_Query($arg);
```